# how to retrieve Firebase json ArrayList inside Arraylist data and store it in Arraylist for display in Textview later

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image] 
I want to retrieve data from fire-base to display later in Text View. but Data-snapshot is not getting all the key and value(i.e. date,month,year) only reaching to date . i need to date month and year in single Text View..
for timing i insert data as String in fire-base..

i did tried to add date value to Array-list but it showing null. when i check in debugger. i know less about debug.

Problem is in Second FOR loop

i need to display account and amount also. In list view date(complete date) ,account and amount i need to display

```
ArrayList<String> account;
ArrayList<String> amount;
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> datedata;

final DateDataHelper dateDataHelper = new DateDataHelper(AccountBillList.this, date, month, year);

myRef = database.getReference("purchasebill");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                billlistHelper = ds.getValue(BilllistHelper.class);
                assert billlistHelper != null;
                account.add(billlistHelper.getAccount());
                amount.add(billlistHelper.getAmount());
                for (DataSnapshot dd : ds.child("datedata").getChildren(){
                    dateDataHelper = dd.getValue(DateDataHelper.class);

                    date.add(dateDataHelper.getDate());
                    month.add(dateDataHelper.getMonth());
                    year.add(dateDataHelper.getYear());
                }
                intendby.add(billlistHelper.getIntendby());
                vendorname.add(billlistHelper.getVendorName());

            }
            billListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


class DateDataHelper {
    private String date;
    private String month;
    private String year;

public DateDataHelper(AccountBillList accountBillList, ArrayList<String> date, ArrayList<String> month, ArrayList<String> year) {
}

public DateDataHelper(String date, String month, String year) {
    this.date = date;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
}
// getter and setter are there over here
}
```

Comment: add a log to check what `dateDataHelper` contains

Comment: variable dd only contains key date and value 12....( during debugging i had seen ).. never used Log.. help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the node `purchasebill`, and then you are looping inside the direct children of `purchasebill` which are `gameworld` and `datamination`.

To solve your problem, you can add a reference to child `datamination` thus it won't loop inside `gameworld`, so you can do the following:

```
myRef.child("datamination").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            billlistHelper = dataSnapshot.getValue(BilllistHelper.class);
            assert billlistHelper != null;
            account.add(billlistHelper.getAccount());
            amount.add(billlistHelper.getAmount());
            for (DataSnapshot dd : dataSnapshot.child("datedata").getChildren(){
                dateDataHelper = dd.getValue(DateDataHelper.class);

                date.add(dateDataHelper.getDate());
                month.add(dateDataHelper.getMonth());
                year.add(dateDataHelper.getYear());
            }
            intendby.add(billlistHelper.getIntendby());
            vendorname.add(billlistHelper.getVendorName());

        }
        billListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: i update  the question . i added 2 lines at the last

Comment: Did you try this answer?

Comment: Red Line under dateDataHelper on hover cursor it say  cannot assign a value to a final variable 'dateDataHelper'

Comment: when i tried it show RED LINE underdateDataHelper  on the below code ...........................................    dateDataHelper = dd.getValue(DateDataHelper.class);

Comment: Getting this error "Variable 'dateDataHelper' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final"

Comment: add `DateDataHelper dateDataHelper = new DateDataHelper(AccountBillList.this, date, month, year);` exactly before your for loop

Comment: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.inventory2.DateDataHelper

Comment: remove the for loop

Comment: i did remove for loop....sorry but i am new to android ... if i remove for loop what about dd(variable)

Comment: Don't use `dd`, do `dateDataHelper = DataSnapshot.getValue(DateDataHelper.class);`

Comment: dont want to ask every single step... not getting any idea...  after applying your step .... followng code becomes redundant ... DateDataHelper dateDataHelper = new DateDataHelper(AccountBillList.this, date, month, year);